# Regexp. Валидация поля с паролем

Tags: javascript, java, регулярные-выражения

Есть поле с паролем. Нужно провалидировать со следующим условием:

минимальная длина пароля 8 символов,
максимальная длина 20 символов,
поле должно содержать латиницу нижний и верхний регистр, не менее 4 букв + спецсимволы.
Пробовал сделать следующим способом - не получилось:

```
(?=.*\d)((?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z]){4,}).{8,20}
```

Comment: Вам принципиально всё это проверять одной регуляркой? А если потом захочется ещё сильнее усложнить условия валидации? Регексп-монстр получится. Сами же через полгода не сможете сходу понять, что там происходит внутри. Почему бы не сделать несколько проверок, объединив их результаты логическим И?

Comment: Если это будет объединено в одну строку, то не принципиально. Есть предложения как это реализовать?

Comment: Так ведь весь jQuery, например, можно объединить в одну строку. Только строка длинная получится. Так делают в продакшене, чтобы уменьшить размер передаваемого клиенту кода - какой в этом смысл при разработке?

Comment: Смысл, подозреваю, в том, что препод лабу сформулировал именно так =)

Comment: Смысл в том, что нужно выполнить условие )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){4}).{8,20}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - сделать по проверке на каждое условие, то есть берёте строку с паролем, и

- проверяете, что она не меньше минимальной длины
- проверяете, что она не больше максимальной длины
- проверяете, соответствует ли регулярному выражению "что угодно, где есть хоть один спецсимвол"
- проверяете, соответствует ли регулярному выражению "что угодно, где есть `(любая буква в нижнем регистре И любая буква в верхнем регистре)x4 штуки`
- и т.д.

Потом применяете логическое И ко всем проверкам и узнаете, сошлись ли все условия, или нет.

Comment: Меня больше всего интерессует только этот пункт: проверяете, соответствует ли регулярному выражению "что угодно, где есть (любая буква в нижнем регистре И любая буква в верхнем регистре)x4 штуки. Не могли бы вы показать пример?

Comment: А еще для удобства пользователя можно не просто говорить "пароль не соответствует критериям", а пояснить, что именно он забыл включить в строку.

Comment: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}$`

Comment: Этот пример не совсем то, что мне нужно. По условию всего символов в пароле должно быть от 8 до 20, а из них 4 буквы.

Comment: Я написал Вам регулярку `что угодно, где есть (любая буква в нижнем регистре И любая буква в верхнем регистре)x4 штуки`. Выше я предложил сделать несколько отельных проверок, это одна из них. Что Вам непонятно? Как объединить результаты проверок?

Comment: Мне не понятно как в одной регулярке выполнить полностью условие, чтобы ограничение было **на весь пароль с 8 до 20 символов, а из них обязательно были 4 буквы**. К символам могут относится цифры, буквы и спецсимволы.

Comment: @Armm, Вы как-то слишком часто меняете показания. Мы с Вами начали беседу с того, что нет смысла реализовывать всё, что Вы хотите, одной регуляркой - это громоздко и неудобно. Я предложил проверки разделить, Вы ответили "Меня больше всего интерессует только этот пункт - ... - Не могли бы вы показать пример?", я дал Вам пример, теперь Вы снова хотите "в одной регулярке выполнить полностью условие". Я не понимаю, какого ответа Вы ждёте - полностью готового кода Вашей задачи? Так здесь делать домашние задания за учащихся не принято. Если не так - извольте недвусмысленно сформулировать Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Не согласен, регулярка получается достаточно простая и хорошая.